# pass value from JSP to ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, jsp

what I want/have to do is give a value (possibly two values) from one JSP-application to a ASP-application, but I don't know if this is even possible.

I myself don't have any experience with JSP. I did learn Java in college, but that's about it. So I don't really know what options I have here.

I think the real problem is how to handle the threading, as it is expected that 50 people use the program at the same time. So I sort of need to have a direct communication.

Does anybody have an idea how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, but your question is a bit muddled.

First off: A JSP is a compiled first to a Java servlet, then to a .class file, deployed in a servlet/JSP engine.  Servlets are listeners for HTTP requests.  You can certainly make calls to a C# object that also listens for HTTP requests.  I'd recommend learning something about AJAX and jQuery to see how it's done.

As for threading, the Java container handles threading for you.  You should write your servlets/JSPs as if they were single threaded.  That means synchronizing shared state in servlets and minimizing or eliminating it whenever possible.

Comment: Ok, I thought that I had to use HTTP requests in some way. I already have a little knowledge regarding that topic, but I guess I'll have to refresh. I'll see what I can find and post any questions here. Thanks for now. :)

Comment: Um - AJAX does mean HTTP.  You were correct.  I thought that pointing out that senders and receivers were all communicating using HTTP made that clear.

Comment: Yea, I know. I used jQuery way back with HTML5 when I wrote my bachelor thesis. Refreshed my knowledge just now and I guess I'll be able to do it. Though I have to speak to the administrator of the JSP application first as he has to provide me with values.